# How to keep logged-in to Facebook in Win Store app?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I’m using Facebook C# SDK to build a Windows Store app which interacts with data in Facebook.
I followed sample project and I could build an app.
But I have one question. 
Login page shows a checkbox “Keep me signed-in”.
I check the box and login to Facebook. But every time I launch the app, the login page is shown and I have to input my account.

I had developed similar app for Windows Phone7 with Facebook C# SDK. With that app, I have to login only once. From 2nd time, it automatically proceeds to content page.

How can I do the same thing for Windows Store App?

Answer (score 1):

you can register on file your AccessToken and reuse it.

I have wrap the fb client in Singleton object and use this code

```
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["AccessToken"]))
        {
            FbClient.Instance.AccessToken = (string)Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["AccessToken"];
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(FBHomePage)); 
        }
        else
        {
            var s = FbClient.Instance.Login(); //as Sdk example...
        }
        FbClient.Instance.LoginSucced += Instance_LoginSucced;
```

and in Instance_LoginSucced

```
    void Instance_LoginSucced(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.Add
        (
            new KeyValuePair<string, object>("AccessToken", FbClient.Instance.AccessToken)
        );

        Frame.Navigate(typeof(FBHomePage));   
    }
```